# How do I fix this error in Anylogic, and what does it mean?

Tags: java, anylogic

I am getting this error from AnyLogic:

```
Exception during discrete event execution:
class network_model2021.NursePractioners cannot be cast to class network_model2021.MedicalRecords (network_model2021.NursePractioners and network_model2021.MedicalRecords are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
at network_model2021.Main$5.resourceSets(Main.java:1)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Seize.f(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Seize.b(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Seize.b(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Seize$11.onEnter(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Wait.e(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Wait.e(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Wait$8.onEnter(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.InputBlock$1.b(Unknown Source)

    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.InPort.a(Unknown Source)
```

Im not sure what it means. I am trying to attach one agent (records) to another agent (nurses).

Comment: This typically means that you are sending an agent to a block that is expecting to receive agents of another type. Can you share an image of the process where you have the seize block?

Comment: search for "typecasting AnyLogic" and you should find out more. Also check the help for type casting